# Real time object tracking - how to let the video play in the beginning, let the user pause it, draw the bounding box, and then begin the tracking?

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, object-detection, video-tracking

Following is a code I found [here](https://learnopencv.com/object-tracking-using-opencv-cpp-python/) for real time object tracking:

```
import cv2
import sys

major_ver, minor_ver, subminor_ver = cv2.__version__.split('.')

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    # Set up tracker.
    tracker_types = ['BOOSTING', 'MIL','KCF', 'TLD', 'MEDIANFLOW', 'GOTURN', 'MOSSE', 'CSRT']
    tracker_type = tracker_types[1]

    if int(minor_ver) < 3:
        tracker = cv2.Tracker_create(tracker_type)
    else:
        if tracker_type == 'BOOSTING':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerBoosting_create()
        if tracker_type == 'MIL':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()
        if tracker_type == 'KCF':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
        if tracker_type == 'TLD':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerTLD_create()
        if tracker_type == 'MEDIANFLOW':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
        if tracker_type == 'GOTURN':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerGOTURN_create()
        if tracker_type == 'MOSSE':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create()
        if tracker_type == "CSRT":
            tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()

    # Read video
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # 0 means webcam. Otherwise if you want to use a video file, replace 0 with "video_file.MOV")

    # Exit if video not opened.
    if not video.isOpened():
        print ("Could not open video")
        sys.exit()

    # Read first frame.
    ok, frame = video.read()
    if not ok:
        print ('Cannot read video file')
        sys.exit()
    
    # Define an initial bounding box
    bbox = (287, 23, 86, 320)

    # Uncomment the line below to select a different bounding box
    bbox = cv2.selectROI(frame, False)

    # Initialize tracker with first frame and bounding box
    ok = tracker.init(frame, bbox)

    while True:
        # Read a new frame
        ok, frame = video.read()
        if not ok:
            break
        
        # Start timer
        timer = cv2.getTickCount()

        # Update tracker
        ok, bbox = tracker.update(frame)

        # Calculate Frames per second (FPS)
        fps = cv2.getTickFrequency() / (cv2.getTickCount() - timer);

        # Draw bounding box
        if ok:
            # Tracking success
            p1 = (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]))
            p2 = (int(bbox[0] + bbox[2]), int(bbox[1] + bbox[3]))
            cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (255,0,0), 2, 1)
        else :
            # Tracking failure
            cv2.putText(frame, "Tracking failure detected", (100,80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,(0,0,255),2)

        # Display tracker type on frame
        cv2.putText(frame, tracker_type + " Tracker", (100,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50),2);
    
        # Display FPS on frame
        cv2.putText(frame, "FPS : " + str(int(fps)), (100,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50), 2);

        # Display result
        cv2.imshow("Tracking", frame)

        # Exit if ESC pressed
        k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
        if k == 27 : break
```

It works fine, but when you run the program, it pauses at the first frame until you draw the bounding box for the tracking to start.

I want to let the video play first, then the user should be able to pause it, draw the bounding box and then resume the video for the tracking to begin. For that, I replaced the following:

```
    # Read video
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # 0 means webcam. Otherwise if you want to use a video file, replace 0 with "video_file.MOV")

    # Exit if video not opened.
    if not video.isOpened():
        print ("Could not open video")
        sys.exit()

    # Read first frame.
    ok, frame = video.read()
    if not ok:
        print ('Cannot read video file')
        sys.exit()

    # Define an initial bounding box
    bbox = (287, 23, 86, 320)

    # Uncomment the line below to select a different bounding box
    bbox = cv2.selectROI(frame, False)

    # Initialize tracker with first frame and bounding box
    ok = tracker.init(frame, bbox)
```

with this:

```
    while True:
        # Read video
        video = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # 0 means webcam. Otherwise if you want to use a video file, replace 0 with "video_file.MOV")

        # Exit if video not opened.
        if not video.isOpened():
            print ("Could not open video")
            sys.exit()

        # Read first frame.
        ok, frame = video.read()
        if not ok:
            print ('Cannot read video file')
            sys.exit()
        
        # Retrieve an image and Display it.
        if(0xFF & cv2.waitKey(10))==ord('p'): # Press key `p` to pause the video to start tracking
            break
        cv2.namedWindow("Image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.imshow("Image", frame)
    cv2.destroyWindow("Image")
```

When I run the program now, the video starts to play in the beginning, but as soon as I press `p`, Python crashes:

[image]

How do I fix this?

**EDIT:** Pasting the entire code with the replacement/substitution here for clarity:

```
import cv2
import sys

major_ver, minor_ver, subminor_ver = cv2.__version__.split('.')

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    # Set up tracker.
    tracker_types = ['BOOSTING', 'MIL','KCF', 'TLD', 'MEDIANFLOW', 'GOTURN', 'MOSSE', 'CSRT']
    tracker_type = tracker_types[1]

    if int(minor_ver) < 3:
        tracker = cv2.Tracker_create(tracker_type)
    else:
        if tracker_type == 'BOOSTING':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerBoosting_create()
        if tracker_type == 'MIL':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()
        if tracker_type == 'KCF':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
        if tracker_type == 'TLD':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerTLD_create()
        if tracker_type == 'MEDIANFLOW':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
        if tracker_type == 'GOTURN':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerGOTURN_create()
        if tracker_type == 'MOSSE':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create()
        if tracker_type == "CSRT":
            tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()

    while True:
        # Read video
        video = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # 0 means webcam. Otherwise if you want to use a video file, replace 0 with "video_file.MOV")

        # Exit if video not opened.
        if not video.isOpened():
            print ("Could not open video")
            sys.exit()

        # Read first frame.
        ok, frame = video.read()
        if not ok:
            print ('Cannot read video file')
            sys.exit()
        
        # Retrieve an image and Display it.
        if((0xFF & cv2.waitKey(10))==ord('p')): # Press key `p` to pause the video to start tracking
            break
        cv2.namedWindow("Image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.imshow("Image", frame)
    cv2.destroyWindow("Image")

    while True:
        # Read a new frame
        ok, frame = video.read()
        if not ok:
            break
        
        # Start timer
        timer = cv2.getTickCount()

        # Update tracker
        ok, bbox = tracker.update(frame)

        # Calculate Frames per second (FPS)
        fps = cv2.getTickFrequency() / (cv2.getTickCount() - timer);

        # Draw bounding box
        if ok:
            # Tracking success
            p1 = (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]))
            p2 = (int(bbox[0] + bbox[2]), int(bbox[1] + bbox[3]))
            cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (255,0,0), 2, 1)
        else :
            # Tracking failure
            cv2.putText(frame, "Tracking failure detected", (100,80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,(0,0,255),2)

        # Display tracker type on frame
        cv2.putText(frame, tracker_type + " Tracker", (100,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50),2);
    
        # Display FPS on frame
        cv2.putText(frame, "FPS : " + str(int(fps)), (100,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50), 2);

        # Display result
        cv2.imshow("Tracking", frame)

        # Exit if ESC pressed
        k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
        if k == 27 : break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your if statement has the parenthesis in the wrong place

```py
if(0xFF & cv2.waitKey(10))==ord('p'):
```

should be

```py
if ((0xFF & cv2.waitKey(10)) == ord('p')):
```

Though if you're using ord() you can do a direct comparison

```py
if (cv2.waitKey(10) == ord('p')):
```

Here's your code with a few edits. It works for tracking my face.

```py
import cv2
import sys

major_ver, minor_ver, subminor_ver = cv2.__version__.split('.')

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    # Set up tracker.
    tracker_types = ['BOOSTING', 'MIL','KCF', 'TLD', 'MEDIANFLOW', 'GOTURN', 'MOSSE', 'CSRT']
    tracker_type = tracker_types[1]

    if int(minor_ver) < 3:
        tracker = cv2.Tracker_create(tracker_type)
    else:
        if tracker_type == 'BOOSTING':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerBoosting_create()
        if tracker_type == 'MIL':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()
        if tracker_type == 'KCF':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
        if tracker_type == 'TLD':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerTLD_create()
        if tracker_type == 'MEDIANFLOW':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
        if tracker_type == 'GOTURN':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerGOTURN_create()
        if tracker_type == 'MOSSE':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create()
        if tracker_type == "CSRT":
            tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()

    # Read video
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # 0 means webcam. Otherwise if you want to use a video file, replace 0 with "video_file.MOV")

    # Exit if video not opened.
    if not video.isOpened():
        print ("Could not open video")
        sys.exit()

    while True:

        # Read first frame.
        ok, frame = video.read()
        if not ok:
            print ('Cannot read video file')
            sys.exit()
        
        # Retrieve an image and Display it.
        if((0xFF & cv2.waitKey(10))==ord('p')): # Press key `p` to pause the video to start tracking
            break
        cv2.namedWindow("Image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.imshow("Image", frame)
    cv2.destroyWindow("Image");

    # select the bounding box
    bbox = (287, 23, 86, 320)

    # Uncomment the line below to select a different bounding box
    bbox = cv2.selectROI(frame, False)

    # Initialize tracker with first frame and bounding box
    ok = tracker.init(frame, bbox)

    while True:
        # Read a new frame
        ok, frame = video.read()
        if not ok:
            break
        
        # Start timer
        timer = cv2.getTickCount()

        # Update tracker
        ok, bbox = tracker.update(frame)

        # Calculate Frames per second (FPS)
        fps = cv2.getTickFrequency() / (cv2.getTickCount() - timer);

        # Draw bounding box
        if ok:
            # Tracking success
            p1 = (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]))
            p2 = (int(bbox[0] + bbox[2]), int(bbox[1] + bbox[3]))
            cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (255,0,0), 2, 1)
        else :
            # Tracking failure
            cv2.putText(frame, "Tracking failure detected", (100,80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,(0,0,255),2)

        # Display tracker type on frame
        cv2.putText(frame, tracker_type + " Tracker", (100,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50),2);
    
        # Display FPS on frame
        cv2.putText(frame, "FPS : " + str(int(fps)), (100,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50), 2);

        # Display result
        cv2.imshow("Tracking", frame)

        # Exit if ESC pressed
        k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
        if k == 27 : break
```

I moved the videocapture declaration outside of the loop so that it's not getting rebuilt every loop iteration. I added back in the ROI selector and tracker initialization inbetween the first and second loops.

Comment: Ok. But this doesn't fix the Python crash upon pressing `p`.

Comment: how are you running the python program? Is there some additional information about what part of the program crashed? Can you post the entire code with your substitution?

Comment: Ok, I've edited the question to include the entire code with substitution. And I am running it like I would run any other Python program - name the file as `tracking.py` and then run it as `python3 tracking.py`.

Comment: is the object_tracker_master thing needed? When I run the program (after removing object_tracker_master) it runs without crashing.

Comment: Oh, yes, please ignore that. I was trying out some other things, so this import was for that. But its not needed here, I forgot to remove that line when I copy-pasted the code here. I've edited the code to remove it now.

Comment: Saw your edited answer. It works, thanks! In addition to this, do you know how to make it such that it can automatically detect any new object coming inside the frame and display a bounding box around it, without needing the user to pause the video and draw the bounding box around it?

Comment: if the camera doesn't move then you can look for changes in the image that occur outside of any bounding box around things you're already tracking. This is kinda its own question though and there's different techniques depending on your environment/setup/tolerances.

Comment: Hi Ian, I put up a new question about how to automatically detect objects and track them here, if you'd like to have a look and have a solution for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66096223/how-to-detect-an-object-real-time-and-track-it-automatically-instead-of-user-ha