# How to detect an object real time and track it automatically, instead of user having to draw a bounding box around the object to be tracked?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, deep-learning, object-detection, video-tracking

I have the following code where the user can press `p` to pause the video, draw a bounding box around the object to be tracked, and then press Enter (carriage return) to track that object in the video feed:

```
import cv2
import sys

major_ver, minor_ver, subminor_ver = cv2.__version__.split('.')

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    # Set up tracker.
    tracker_types = ['BOOSTING', 'MIL','KCF', 'TLD', 'MEDIANFLOW', 'GOTURN', 'MOSSE', 'CSRT']
    tracker_type = tracker_types[1]

    if int(minor_ver) < 3:
        tracker = cv2.Tracker_create(tracker_type)
    else:
        if tracker_type == 'BOOSTING':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerBoosting_create()
        if tracker_type == 'MIL':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()
        if tracker_type == 'KCF':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
        if tracker_type == 'TLD':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerTLD_create()
        if tracker_type == 'MEDIANFLOW':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
        if tracker_type == 'GOTURN':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerGOTURN_create()
        if tracker_type == 'MOSSE':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create()
        if tracker_type == "CSRT":
            tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()

    # Read video
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # 0 means webcam. Otherwise if you want to use a video file, replace 0 with "video_file.MOV")

    # Exit if video not opened.
    if not video.isOpened():
        print ("Could not open video")
        sys.exit()

    while True:

        # Read first frame.
        ok, frame = video.read()
        if not ok:
            print ('Cannot read video file')
            sys.exit()
        
        # Retrieve an image and Display it.
        if((0xFF & cv2.waitKey(10))==ord('p')): # Press key `p` to pause the video to start tracking
            break
        cv2.namedWindow("Image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.imshow("Image", frame)
    cv2.destroyWindow("Image");

    # select the bounding box
    bbox = (287, 23, 86, 320)

    # Uncomment the line below to select a different bounding box
    bbox = cv2.selectROI(frame, False)

    # Initialize tracker with first frame and bounding box
    ok = tracker.init(frame, bbox)

    while True:
        # Read a new frame
        ok, frame = video.read()
        if not ok:
            break
        
        # Start timer
        timer = cv2.getTickCount()

        # Update tracker
        ok, bbox = tracker.update(frame)

        # Calculate Frames per second (FPS)
        fps = cv2.getTickFrequency() / (cv2.getTickCount() - timer);

        # Draw bounding box
        if ok:
            # Tracking success
            p1 = (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]))
            p2 = (int(bbox[0] + bbox[2]), int(bbox[1] + bbox[3]))
            cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (255,0,0), 2, 1)
        else :
            # Tracking failure
            cv2.putText(frame, "Tracking failure detected", (100,80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,(0,0,255),2)

        # Display tracker type on frame
        cv2.putText(frame, tracker_type + " Tracker", (100,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50),2);
    
        # Display FPS on frame
        cv2.putText(frame, "FPS : " + str(int(fps)), (100,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50), 2);

        # Display result
        cv2.imshow("Tracking", frame)

        # Exit if ESC pressed
        k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
        if k == 27 : break
```

Now, instead of having the user pause the video and draw the bounding box around the object, how  do I make it such that it can automatically detect the particular object I am interested in (which is toothbrush in my case) whenever it is introduced in the video feed, and then track it?

I found [this](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/detecting-objects-in-videos-and-camera-feeds-using-keras-opencv-and-imageai-c869fe1ebcdb) article which talks about how we can detect objects in video using ImageAI and Yolo.

```
from imageai.Detection import VideoObjectDetection
import os
import cv2

execution_path = os.getcwd()

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 

detector = VideoObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
detector.setModelPath(os.path.join(execution_path , "yolo.h5"))
detector.loadModel()

video_path = detector.detectObjectsFromVideo(camera_input=camera,
                                output_file_path=os.path.join(execution_path, "camera_detected_1")
                                , frames_per_second=29, log_progress=True)
print(video_path)
```

Now, Yolo does detect toothbrush, it is among the 80 odd objects that it can detect by default. However, there are 2 points about this article that makes it not the ideal solution for me:

1. This method first analyses each video frame (takes about 1-2 seconds per frame, so about 1 minute to analyse a 2-3 second video stream from the webcam), and saves the detected video in a separate video file. Whereas, I want to detect the toothbrush in the webcam video feed in real time. Is there a solution for this?
2. The Yolo v3 model being used can detect all 80 objects, but I want only 2 or 3 objects detected - the toothbrush, the person holding the toothbrush and the background possibly, if needed at all. So, is there a way in which I can reduce the model weight by selecting only these 2 or 3 objects to detect?

Comment: You dont use darknet framework ?

Comment: I have no idea about it. I don't have much experience in the field of Computer Vision, I'm just trying to get into it.  So, if you think darknet can help solve this problem, I'd appreciate it greatly if you could please write an answer about how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a quick and easy solution, you can use one of the more lightweight yolo files. You can get the weights and config files (they come in pairs and must be used together) from this website: https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/ (don't worry, it looks sketch but it's fine)

Using a smaller network will get you much higher fps, but also worse accuracy. If that's a tradeoff you're willing to accept then this is the easiest thing to do.

Here's some code for detecting toothbrushes. The first file is just a class file to help make using the Yolo network more seamless. The second is the "main" file that opens up a VideoCapture and feeds images to the network.

yolo.py

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

class Yolo:
    def __init__(self, cfg, weights, names, conf_thresh, nms_thresh, use_cuda = False):
        # save thresholds
        self.ct = conf_thresh;
        self.nmst = nms_thresh;

        # create net
        self.net = cv2.dnn.readNet(weights, cfg);
        print("Finished: " + str(weights));
        self.classes = [];
        file = open(names, 'r');
        for line in file:
            self.classes.append(line.strip());

        # use gpu + CUDA to speed up detections
        if use_cuda:
            self.net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA);
            self.net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA);

        # get output names
        layer_names = self.net.getLayerNames();
        self.output_layers = [layer_names[i[0]-1] for i in self.net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()];

    # runs detection on the image and draws on it
    def detect(self, img, target_id):
        # get detection stuff
        b, c, ids, idxs = self.get_detection_data(img, target_id);

        # draw result
        img = self.draw(img, b, c, ids, idxs);
        return img, len(idxs);

    # returns boxes, confidences, class_ids, and indexes (indices?)
    def get_detection_data(self, img, target_id):
        # get output
        layer_outputs = self.get_inf(img);

        # get dims
        height, width = img.shape[:2];

        # filter thresholds and target
        b, c, ids, idxs = self.thresh(layer_outputs, width, height, target_id);
        return b, c, ids, idxs;

    # runs the network on an image
    def get_inf(self, img):
        # construct a blob
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1 / 255.0, (416,416), swapRB=True, crop=False);

        # get response
        self.net.setInput(blob);
        layer_outputs = self.net.forward(self.output_layers);
        return layer_outputs;

    # filters the layer output by conf, nms and id
    def thresh(self, layer_outputs, width, height, target_id):
        # some lists
        boxes = [];
        confidences = [];
        class_ids = [];

        # each layer outputs
        for output in layer_outputs:
            for detection in output:
                # get id and confidence
                scores = detection[5:];
                class_id = np.argmax(scores);
                confidence = scores[class_id];

                # filter out low confidence
                if confidence > self.ct and class_id == target_id:
                    # scale bounding box back to the image size
                    box = detection[0:4] * np.array([width, height, width, height]);
                    (cx, cy, w, h) = box.astype('int');

                    # grab the top-left corner of the box
                    tx = int(cx - (w / 2));
                    ty = int(cy - (h / 2));

                    # update lists
                    boxes.append([tx,ty,int(w),int(h)]);
                    confidences.append(float(confidence));
                    class_ids.append(class_id);

        # apply NMS
        idxs = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, self.ct, self.nmst);
        return boxes, confidences, class_ids, idxs;

    # draw detections on image
    def draw(self, img, boxes, confidences, class_ids, idxs):
        # check for zero
        if len(idxs) > 0:
            # loop over indices
            for i in idxs.flatten():
                # extract the bounding box coords
                (x,y) = (boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1]);
                (w,h) = (boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3]);

                # draw a box
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), 2);

                # draw text
                text = "{}: {:.4}".format(self.classes[class_ids[i]], confidences[i]);
                cv2.putText(img, text, (x, y-5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0,0,255), 2);
        return img;
```

main.py

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# this is the "yolo.py" file, I assume it's in the same folder as this program
from yolo import Yolo

# these are the filepaths of the yolo files
weights = "yolov3-tiny.weights";
config = "yolov3-tiny.cfg";
labels = "yolov3.txt";

# init yolo network
target_class_id = 79; # toothbrush
conf_thresh = 0.4; # less == more boxes (but more false positives)
nms_thresh = 0.4; # less == more boxes (but more overlap)
net = Yolo(config, weights, labels, conf_thresh, nms_thresh);

# open video capture
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0);

# loop
done = False;
while not done:
    # get frame
    ret, frame = cap.read();
    if not ret:
        done = cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q');
        continue;

    # do detection
    frame, _ = net.detect(frame, target_class_id);

    # show
    cv2.imshow("Marked", frame);
    done = cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q');
```

There are a few options for you if you don't want to use a lighter weights file.

If you have an Nvidia GPU you can use CUDA to *drastically* increase your fps. Even modest nvidia gpu's are several times faster than running solely on cpu.

A common strategy to bypass the cost of constantly running detection is to only use it to initially acquire a target. You can use the detection from the neural net to initialize your object tracker, similar to a person drawing a bounding box around the object. Object trackers are way faster and there's no need to constantly do a full detection every frame.

If you run Yolo and object tracking in a separate thread then you can run as fast as your camera is capable of. You'll need to store a history of frames so that when the Yolo thread finishes a frame you can check the old frame to see if you're already tracking the object, and so you can start the object tracker on the corresponding frame and fast-forward it to let it catch up. This program isn't simple and you'll need to make sure you're managing data between your threads correctly. It's a good excercise for becoming comfortable with multithreading though, which is a huge step in programming.

Comment: Thanks Ian. i downloaded the `.weights` and `.cfg` files and downloaded them to the same folder as where these two `.py` files are saved. But when I run `main.py`, I get the following error: `File "yolo.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.net = cv2.dnn.readNet(weights, cfg);
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) /private/var/folders/nz/vv4_9tw56nv9k3tkvyszvwg80000gn/T/pip-req-build-yvyj7qlp/opencv/modules/dnn/src/darknet/darknet_importer.cpp:207: error: (-212:Parsing error) Failed to parse NetParameter file: yolov3-tiny.cfg in function 'readNetFromDarknet'`

Comment: it's saying it can't find the config file. Make sure the filename in the code matches the config file you downloaded.

Comment: Got it working. You're right, the names of the `.weights` and `.cfg` files I downloaded was different than what the code was expecting. I also replaced the YoloV3 model with YoloV4, and adjusted the `conf_thresh` and `nms_thresh` values to get it to work better in my environment (lighting conditions, webcam quality, the object to be detected, etc) than the YoloV3 model. Thanks! Now, if I want to detect whether the toothbrush is inside the person's mouth or not, how do I do that? Because Yolo can't detect the mouth of a person, it can only detect the person as a whole, right?

Comment: yeah, the weights from the website were trained on the coco dataset, so just whole people. OpenCV can do facial landmarks in real time. Use that to look for the mouth and check if the toothbrush is overlapping it.

Answer (score 0):

I want to answer this question with the help of [this article](https://learnopencv.com/deep-learning-based-object-detection-using-yolov3-with-opencv-python-c/) which I also used before and met the similar problem with yours. Here are the suggestions:

- Run YOLOv3 with [darknet framework](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/) which will increase the performance.
- In your code snippet, it looks it doesn't let you to decide network input width and height so I don't know what you are using for them. Decreasing network width and height will increase the speed but oppositely decrease the accuracy.
- YOLOv3 trained for 80 objects but you only need some of them. I also only needed the cars in my project before. Unfortunately, you can't manipulate the weight file which is already trained and also you can not train your objects such well.
- The other way I also tried before is that I transfered YOLOv3 to another thread and I also didnt apply yolo to all frames. I only applied some of them, for example: 1 frame of each 10 frame. This was also helpful for me.
- Or you can choose a better cpu pc :)